# android "force close" what exactly happen with memory

Tags: android, memory, service, heap-memory, forceclose

I have few services in my application. Application is running in "android.uid.system" process. When I click "force close" then logs says :

Force stopping package com.sec.ims.android uid=1000
Force stopping service ServiceRecord{42b9a948 ...
.....

I see that for each service running under my application. There in no onDestroy() call at all. I am wondering what exactly android is doing after "force close" ? Stopping whole process or just stopping all services, activities working under application ?

Do you know what happen with objects, static variables and threads which were created by those services ? Does android erase all memory heap for this application ?

Answer (score 1):

A Force Stop will kill the VM (Virtual Machine) in which the application is running. All Objects, Services, and activities are killed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you started the service.

Using [`startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) overrides the default service lifetime that is managed by [`bindService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29).

When `startService()` is used, your service life-cycle remains when the original Activity is closed.

In both cases Android stops the services when memory is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think. This problem is low memory killer running problem.
Android PF have kill alive process when heigher priority process need heap.

[ps]

- if you create Low Memory Killer situation on purpose. 
  I recommend that you use following my application.
  http://kyorohiro.blogspot.jp/2013/02/inside-kyorostress-1-produce-low-memory.html
- if this issue is Low memory Killer problem, your service and process will be restarted . but your application 's data is erased in java heap.
- if PF restart your process. then call onCreate().
- Service lifesycle is changed operation by onStartCommand 's return value. check android api refernce.